# Error 0x80240017 While Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, php, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to setup DUO Access Gateway for two factor authentication.
Official documentation is given [here](https://duo.com/docs/dag).
Which needs php-7.0.14-nts-Win32-VC14-x64 to run.

I've also installed  Windows 10 Universal C Runtime (CRT) from Windows update which is KB2999226.
DAG depends upon Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015. While installation of that package I'm facing Error:0x80240017

Complete error log is:

```
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\VC_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: '/uninstall -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{6A18E564-8426-4F96-8B7D-528BD6F59DA9} {AEBDBE13-4F2E-43CB-9703-53CD353D2A5B} 5064' 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170108110004.log' 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i000: Setting version variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKey' to value '10.0.10046.0' 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 1 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:04]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Repair 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170108110004_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log' 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true. 
[0/pre>F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170108110004_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i300: Apply begin 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i360: Creating a system restore point. 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created. 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No 
[13C8:07B4][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi. 
[13C8:07B4][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab. 
[13C8:07B4][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi. 
[13C8:07B4][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab. 
[13C8:07B4][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu. 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"' 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:06]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"' 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:07]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:07]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:07]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart' 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:08]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:08]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package. 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:08]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:08]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package. 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:08]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No 
[13C8:1318][2017-01-08T11:00:08]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No 
[0F8C:1138][2017-01-08T11:00:08]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart: No
```

Comment: any update on your issue? Is it solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu` fails to install with the error `0x80240017` wich means the update doesn't apply to your system (wrong architecture, update already replaced by newer one with is installed):

```
//
// MessageId: WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE
//
// MessageText:
//
// Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates.
//
#define WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE              _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80240017L)
```

Microsoft deployed the a newer version of the Univeral C Runtime with [KB3118401](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118401). Look if you have the Update KB3118401 installed and if yes, remove the update KB3118401, reboot and try again to install the Runtime.

Comment: I solved my problem by using a third party tool for windows update and a apt-get like package manager named as [chocolaty](https://chocolatey.org/)