# 0x80240017 error when installing windows update (manually)

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update, uninstall

I am running an installer which install bunch of things including certain windows update. This installer is failing and windows event viewer shows here:

```
Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2149842967 "" (Command line: "wusa.exe C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Temp\{BC46DCE0-7B92-11D5-B883-00105AA46329}\Windows6.1-KB917607-x86.msu /quiet")
```

The error code 0x80240017 (or 2149842967) [indicates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd939837(v=ws.10))

0x80240017 = WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE = Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates.

This was caused me manually removing an application from control panel because it will not get installed through typical add/remove programs from control panel.

How can I come around this or remove any lingering components that maybe causing this? I have a lot of stuff on PC, so can't uninstall everything.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to install an update that doesn't apply to your system.  Which exact version/edition of Windows 7 are you trying to install it on?  That's a 32-bit patch, so it won't run on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes my system is 64 bit windows but this installer always used to install it correctly (or at least appropriate version of it) but this is happening since I uninstalled the main application manually (which requires & installs these).

Comment: There is a 64-bit version of that patch, go grab it and try it.

Comment: Which update?  Edit your question

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1164742/174557